# A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled error in ReactJS with UseState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an input component, when the amount increases the warning "A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the componen" show up

The code:

```
const [month,setMonth]=useState([])
for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        tabs.push(
            <tr key={i}>
                <td className="align-baseline">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        className="form-control"
                        required
                        value={month[i]}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                            let array = month;
                            array[i] = e.target.value;
                            setMonth(array);
                        }}
                    />
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
```

I saw some solutions that put`value = {month [i] || ""}`, but when i do that the state only updates when I increase the amount and even then it doesn't take all the numbers, for example if I type 122, it only shows the 2.

How could i get the value and update the state without error?

Comment: You can do `value={month[i]||''}` you can't set it to undefined because React will think it's an uncontrolled component. You are also mutating try this: `let array = [...month];`

Comment: thanks bro, for some reason the ```let array = month``` was changing blocking the ```value={month||""}```

Answer (score 0):

The warning you're encountering is because React is detecting a change from an uncontrolled to a controlled input, or vice versa. To resolve this, you should ensure that the value prop of the input is always controlled. The issue you described with only the last digit being displayed is likely due to a common misconception about how React updates state.

Here's a corrected version of your code:

```
const [month, setMonth] = useState([]);

const handleInputChange = (index, value) => {
    let newArray = [...month]; // Create a new array to avoid mutating the state directly
    newArray[index] = value;
    setMonth(newArray);
};

const tabs = [];
for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    tabs.push(
        <tr key={i}>
            <td className="align-baseline">
                <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    required
                    value={month[i] || ''} // Use an empty string if the value is undefined
                    onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(i, e.target.value)}
                />
            </td>
        </tr>
    );
}
```

In this corrected code:

I've changed the state update logic to use the spread operator ([...month]) to create a new array, preventing direct mutation of the state.
The value prop of the input is set to month[i] || '', ensuring that it's always a controlled input. If month[i] is undefined, it defaults to an empty string.
This should resolve the warning and also update the state correctly. If you're still facing issues, make sure to check other parts of your code that may be affecting the state or the rendering of your component.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.